# How to receive transfer/receive parameters in PHP and SOAP?

Tags: php, soap

I'm new to SOAP and I stuck for 2 days now. Basically I can't 'pull' parameters from array that is passed to function. Does anyone knows why? My WSDL file is here: [link](http://eqa-webservice.denobi.org/EQA.wsdl)

I'm trying to call function like that:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://mydomain.com/EQA.wsdl",array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

$data = array('SearchValue' => 'road', 'Referrer' => 's' , 'BuyerOrganisation' => 'c');

echo $client->SearchByContractorName($data);
```

Thanks for any help,

eloleon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$client->__call('SearchByContractorName', $data)
```

Comment: Thanks silly for your quick response, but still no joy with it. Only first character off first parameter is 'available.'

Here is what what I'm doing with that function

`code` $data = array('SearchValue' => 'road', 'Referrer' => 's' , 'BuyerOrganisation' => 'c');`code`



`code` echo $client->__call('SearchByContractorName', $data) `code`

Then in Server.php file I have that:

`code`public function SearchByContractorName($data) {

  return contractors::doSearch($data);
 }`code`

Comment: And in contractors class I do that:

`code`
public function doSearch($data)
 {
  
 # VALUES FROM SOAP

 $SearchValue = $data['SearchValue'];
 $Referrer = $data['Referrer'];
 $BuyerOrganisation = $data['BuyerOrganisation']; `code`

Is it something wrong with WSDL file that won't allow to pass paramaters in array?

Sorry for bad formatting, don't know how to use it properly

eloleon